# How to add and remove a LI from UL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do i use jQuery to add and remove item from unordered lists?
When i doubleclick on an item in list 1 it should be removed from list 1 and added to list 2
And of course, the other way around as well...

I've got the following lists:

```
<ul id='attached'>
  <li id='itemID_1' ondblclick='removeAttached(&#39;itemID_1&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_2' ondblclick='removeAttached(&#39;itemID_2&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_3' ondblclick='removeAttached(&#39;itemID_3&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_4' ondblclick='removeAttached(&#39;itemID_4&#39;)'>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul id='non-attached'>
  <li id='itemID_5' ondblclick='addAttached(&#39;itemID_5&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_6' ondblclick='addAttached(&#39;itemID_6&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_7' ondblclick='addAttached(&#39;itemID_7&#39;)'>Item</li>
  <li id='itemID_8' ondblclick='addAttached(&#39;itemID_8&#39;)'>Item</li>
</ul>
```

I was thinking something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>")
  function addAttached(i) { $('#non-attached').remove(i); $('#attached').append(i); };")
  function removeAttached(i) { $('#attached').remove(i); $('#non-attached').append(i); };")
</script>")
```

But i might be pretty off here?

Comment: Why don't you try this first ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move things back and forth, your best bet is [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
<ul id='attached'>
    <li id='itemID_1'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_2'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_3'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_4'>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul id='non-attached'>
    <li id='itemID_5'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_6'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_7'>Item</li>
    <li id='itemID_8'>Item</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("#attached").delegate("li", "dblclick", function() {
    $("#non-attached").append(this);
});

$("#non-attached").delegate("li", "dblclick", function() {
    $("#attached").append(this);
});
```

This will detect a click on an `li` element which bubbles up to your list.  Then it will move the element to the other list.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TYwPU/

Comment: I see it working in the fiddle. But if i copy/paste it into my asp document, it just wont work. And i get no errors :(

Comment: Are you putting the code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block?

Comment: Yes i am :/ I just added the whole thing to fresh document. And there it worked like a charm. So i have NO idea why it wont work in the document i need it to. Could it be that it is interfering with my jQueryUI tabs?

Comment: If i put it all in the top of my document, it works.. thats pretty odd... Oh well, i'll try figuring it out.. thanks for the answer mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `remove` the element, you can just call [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$("#attached li").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#non-attached");
});
$("#non-attached li").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#attached");
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/7/). Note that the above code should be placed in a `ready` event handler, and it removes the need for inline event handlers.

**Update** based on comments

Because the element is removed from the DOM and reattached somewhere else, it loses the event handler that was bound to it. That means you need to use the jQuery [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods, which bind event handlers to elements matching the selector now or in the future:

```
$("#attached li").live("dblclick", function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#non-attached");
});
$("#non-attached li").live("dblclick", function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#attached");
});
```

Comment: Nice functions james.. Although: It removes but doesnt add.. :/

Comment: @erizias - See my update (I've updated the example fiddle too).

Comment: Invoking the `$` function twice is a little redundant, you can get away with just `append`ing the DOM element `this`, as in my example.

Comment: I see it working in the fiddle. But if i copy/paste it into my asp document, it just wont work.. This answer removes but doesnt add, while Dennis' doesnt do anything.. And i get no errors :(

Comment: Dennis - Very true, not sure what I was thinking. `appendTo` will take a selector as an argument so in my version it's fine to simply remove the call to `$`. erizias - I don't know what's wrong then, but it must be something else in your code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid writing inline javascript. It makes it harder to debug and maintain your codebase. I recommend that you read the following articles on javascript events:

[Quirksmode - Early Event Handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)

[Quirksmode - Traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

This type of event handling should not be mixed with jQuery. Follow @james-allardice example and try learning how javacript should be used correctly. I recommend that you read the jQuery docs and tutorials [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

Also, if you are in a hurry you could try the more appealing [JQuery UI Sortable lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).